# Search specific text from Web page view source and copy full complete line using VBA Macros

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to get a full line of specific text from webpage view source using Excel VBA. I could able to find the text but unable to get in a cell. below is my VBA code

```
Sub latlong()

Dim IE As Object
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate Range("p2")

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

mes = IE.document.body.innerHTML
If InStr(mes, "var point") = 0 Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("q2").Value = "Not Found"
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("q2").Value = "Found"
       End If



 IE.Quit

    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

I want to copy the full line of specific text below is an example text which I am trying to extract from a web page

```
var point = new GLatLng(17.71697,083.30275);
```

I didn't find any suitable answer for my question please help me

Comment: Where is the URL please? And/ Or the relevant HTML (as an insert with snippet tool - not as image)..

Comment: I would use XMLHTTP and RegExp to fetch a string. What is the URL and what you're trying to get from HTML?

Comment: Are you trying to put the latitude in one cell and the longitude in another cell, or are you just trying to drop the entire line into a cell?

Comment: If you share the html/url there might be other solutions to your problem by the way.

Comment: can you share that solution? the line itself a source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know where the line starts, it remains only to extract the line from start to end. The line ends with a semi-colon. The answer should be this simple:

```
Sub latlong()

Dim IE As Object
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim codeLine as String
Dim startPos as Long

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate Range("p2")

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

mes = IE.document.body.innerHTML

startPos = InStr(mes, "var point")
If startPos = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("q2").Value = "Not Found"
Else
    codeLine = Mid(mes, startPos, InStr(startPos, mes, ";") - startPos)
    ActiveSheet.Range("q2").Value = codeLine
End If

IE.Quit

Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

No RegEx Required. :-)

Comment: Your solution is working great but creating duplicate values when using in for loop

Comment: The solution is designed to always find the first occurrence of "var point".  If there are multiple lines in web page body, then you will need to create a smart loop the keeps searching the remainder of the file.

Comment: no there is no multiple lines with "var point". i am not get all values as duplicate only few times.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, I recommend you post a new question with your new code. I suspect that you will also need to provide some sample data.

Comment: if possible please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245185/getting-repeated-data-while-scraping-webpage-using-excel-vba